# UIPasteboard String Origin Data?

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

Is there a way to retrieve which app the contents of the clipboard on iOS was copied from?

So "http://google.com" was copied from Safari, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. It would probably violate the 'sandbox' principle which is implemented throughout iOS.

The only similar feature I know of is `UIApplicationDelegate`'s method [`- application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:) where the source application is explicitly passed as a parameter.

Comment: Hmm, I see. What would be the best way then to cover the security aspect of retrieving a user's clipboard. Especially with apps like 1Password.

Comment: That's Apple's concern, not yours. And one of the reasons I don't use apps like that in the first place.

Comment: So we rely on the review process to detect apps that send info back to a server or something. There should be some sort of pasteboard type like UIPasteboardSecurePasteboard where those things get copied to (the app could dictate), and then in order to retrieve that pasteboard, you need user permission.